Does anyone have idea about what are the specific changes in permissions & services for the android 15?

I just want to know that what changes i need to update in the existing code related to foreground services & permissions?

Although i tried nothing for the above explaination , as i didn't get any information regarding that which changes i need to make in the existing code regarding the permssions and forground services.



Probably everything relevant is covered somewhere in here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15 and there's a similar page for each Android version.
